# How to close an html5 color picker?

Tags: javascript, html, macos, google-chrome

In chrome on OSX when you select a color using a input with type=color:

```html
<input name="color" type="color" />
```

The color picker stays open even after choosing a color. It stays open even when you reload the page.

How can I close this picker popup when a color is chosen?

Comment: Do you know your missing an ending quotation mark?

Comment: Yeah that was a typo, fixed

Comment: I clicked the red close button top left. Mac OS X El Capitan v10.11.1.

Comment: After doing some research, it looks to me like there is no way to close the color picker window programmatically.

Comment: Is there a plan to add it? This is causing issues and I can't believe it's just an uncontrollable UI element that is inaccessible in JS and that this is an acceptable state of affairs.

Comment: I guess there are no plans to make it "controllable" since it's being used as part of the browser / operating system. Just like an alert dialog that behaves differently between platforms.

Answer (score 4):

The color picker depends heavily on a per-browser, per-platform implementation. There's technically no way to close the color picker programatically as a cross-browser solution.

What you can do instead is using a Javascript solution to render your own, cross-platform color picker like [jscolor](http://jscolor.com/) or similar, those even have proper touch support.

Edit: [In this list](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#the-input-element) you can see there's no `close` event in the `input type="color"`. Further reading tells me that since this is just an input like a text input or range input, it's not something you can "control". The alternative may be creating your own.

Comment: So where can I find how to tackle this for each browser? I can't find any documentation on an api for this in chrome, and using any 3rd party libraries is not currently allowed.

Comment: Sadly, and since each browser has its own way to handle this selector, you may want to go through each documentation. [I checked Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/color) but they're not that specific. The [W3 recommendation docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#color-state-%28type=color%29) just gave enough information on how each browser should behave regarding picking a color, but the part about closing it is nowhere.

Comment: [MDN just says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input) that "A color picker's UI has no required features other than accepting simple colors as text", so I guess that's also open for interpretation.

Comment: PS: If you could explain your downvote I'll appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This is a old question I stumbled on looking for the same answer.  I ended up getting the desired effect by flipping the type attribute to 'text', then back to 'color'.

Figured I'd share in case anyone else is stumbling onto this same post.

```
// vanilla JS:
input.setAttribute('type','text');
input.setAttribute('type','color');

// jQuery:
$input.attr('type','text').attr('type','color');
```

```js
// see it in action!

var input = document.getElementById('my-color');

// when you click the color picker, we'll run our code to close it after 2 seconds.
input.addEventListener('focus', function() {
  setTimeout(()=>{
  
    // toggle the type attribute to close the picker!
    input.setAttribute('type','text');
    input.setAttribute('type','color');
    
  }, 2000);
});
```

```html
<input type="color" value="#ffaacc" id="my-color"/> <- Click me
```

Comment: Josh your answer is fine, and please continue to answer old questions for which you have an original and working solutions. I'd just like to note that you can make your code a [live snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do), and that you may want to include a note that this unfortunately works only in some browsers (FF on macOs fails for instance).

Comment: pity, this solution no longer works on Firefox 92...